# Java HttpServletRequest parameters are empty while making post call from Angular 6 Httpclient

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot

I'm trying to send username and password from Angular 6 client to my Spring boot Authentication Service.

Authentication Service is working as I can hit the REST APT from "Advance Rest client" chrome extension but when I try to access the Authentication Service my Angular client not able to send the request body of username and password.
Here is my code:

```
getUserDetails(username, password) {
const body = {
  'username': username,
  'password': password
};

return this.http.post<TokenParams>('http://localhost:8080/login',
  body,
  {
    headers: {
      'content-type':"application/json",
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
    }
  }
);
```

}

I'm able to validate request body from Java code but it is returning empty String (it returns the correct output from chrome extension):

```
System.out.println("Request Body:\n" + req.getReader().lines() .collect( Collectors.joining( System.lineSeparator())));
```

Please let me know is there something am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like a CORS issue to me, have you tried adding the CORS support into your SpringBoot project as well? https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

Comment: can you check the browser console to see if you're seeing any errors ?

Comment: @MarceloTataje Yes CSRF protection is disabled. `httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()`